# Show android floatingactionbutton without tint color

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I trying to hide the tint color of FAB and fill the tint color area with FAB icon image itselt (complete FAB area filled with icon). Have searched but haven't found any solution to this so far. Here is the XML i used to create FAB icon. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/question_hand"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ImageButton and position it yourself with `android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"` (when using a LinearLayout) or inside a RelativeLayout:

`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"`

Comment: Thanks Rob, this server the purpose well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using floatingActionButton you can use a simple ImageView or ImageButton, just set your root element a framelayout:

```
<FrameLayout>
<YourCurrentLayout>
<ImageView> //Replace the FAB, set the gravity and margin as desired
</Framelayout>
```